# How can i run php script when page is fully loaded

Tags: php, jquery

I am fetching tweets and showing them into the slider . now when i open the page it shows me all the tweets one above another which create a mess. and after page fully loaded it shows me tweets as i wanted . so is there any way to show tweets or run php code when page is fully loaded ?

Comment: You can use Ajax calls to do this, see jquery. What basically happens is that you execute a PHP script from Javascript and put it into an element on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all your tweets are output via php, and then styled into a slider with javascript, so in between the data being output and the javascript loading, you see the unstyled data.

A simple solution would be to give the containing element a style of display:none, then show it via javascript when the page has loaded:

css

```
#tweet-holder{
    display:none;
}
```

php / html

```
<div id="tweet-holder">
    //all your tweets go here
</div>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('#tweet-holder').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP code can not be run once the page has loaded, however you can run an AJAX call to a php script.

Although, I would suggest you can run Javascript/jQuery once the page is loaded. Your best bet is to use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

This will provide all the code you should need.